# Deduction guide (or other solution) for choosing function overload

Tags: c++, c++17

I have an overloaded function. 2 of the overloads are

```
void foo(std::string_view v);
void foo(MyClass m);
```

Where `MyClass` has a converting constructor from `std::string`. How can I force a call to `foo(std::string{})` to call the first one? Right now it doesn't compile with error:

> error: call of overloaded ‘foo(std::__cxx11::basic_string&)’ is ambiguous

Comment: make the constructor explicit

Comment: Always post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Write `void foo(const std::string&)` and forward to the first one?

Comment: In general do NOT write code that depends on implicit conversions (that's why the advice is there to add an explicit constructor). That might mean you sometimes need to write a bit of extra code but it really can avoid nasty bugs (in bigger projects where chains of implicit conversions can happen). IMO implicit conversions should never have been part of the language

Comment: Nothing in the OP's question suggests a class is involved. You can't use `explicit` with standalone functions

Comment: I may not have control over the class. Consider overloads taking `std::string_view` and `std::span<char>`. `std::string` can go to either, but I probably want the `string_view` one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add one more overload that uses `static_cast` to call the `string_view` overload as shown below:

```
void foo(const std::string& t) 
{
     std::cout << "std::string\n";
     foo(static_cast<std::string_view>(t));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hbzvG4n4s)

Answer (score 4):

You can make the constructor explicit

```
struct MyClass {
    explicit MyClass(const std::string&) {}
};
```

or cast the argument

```
foo(static_cast<std::string_view>(std::string{}));
```

or cast a pointer to the function

```
static_cast<void(*)(std::string_view)>(&foo)(std::string{});
```

you can make the overload that should rank lower a template function

```
template <typename T = void> void foo(MyClass m) {}
```

The list is not complete. The first option should be prefered, because implicit conversions are generally to be avoided. Note the difference of the above approaches. Making the constructor explicit causes only one of the two overloads to be viable. The casts explicitly select one of the two (otherwise equally good) overloads. Eventually, turning the other overload into a template, keeps both overloads as alternatives but makes the desired one rank better for overload resolution.

Comment: I should warn against the casting to string_view from an inline constructed string. It will go out of scope potentially before its data is accessed.

Comment: @Tates it goes out of scope only when the function returns. Anyhow this is just what OP is asking for. They want `foo(std::string{})` to call `void foo(std::string_view v);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static cast, just force convert into std::string_view.